# python asynchronous context manager

Tags: python, asynchronous, contextmanager

In Python Lan Ref. 3.4.4, it is said that `__aenter__()` and `__aexit__()` must return awaitables. However, in the example async context manager, these two methods return None:

```
class AsyncContextManager:
    async def __aenter__(self):
        await log('entering context')

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
        await log('exiting context')
```

Is this code correct?

Answer (score 7):

`__aenter__` and `__aexit__` must return awaitables, but look what happens when you call the ones in the example:

```
>>> class AsyncContextManager:
...     async def __aenter__(self):
...         await log('entering context')
...     async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
...         await log('exiting context')
... 
>>> AsyncContextManager().__aenter__()
<coroutine object AsyncContextManager.__aenter__ at 0x7f5b092d5ac0>
```

It didn't return `None`! We got a coroutine object, which is awaitable.

These methods are `async` functions, which automatically return (awaitable) asynchronous coroutines. `return` statements in the body of an `async` function determine what gets returned when you `await` the coroutine, not what gets returned when you call the function.

This is similar to how generator functions return generator iterators, even though they usually have no `return` statement, and how if you write `__iter__` as a generator function, you should not try to `return` an iterator inside the generator function.

---

So what happens if you do put a `return` in `__aenter__` or `__aexit__` defined as `async` functions? Well, you can, and if you do, the `return` statement doesn't have to return an awaitable. Here's what Python will do.

If you `return` something from an `__aenter__` defined as an `async` function, that determines what gets bound to an `as` target, if the `async with` uses `as`.

If you `return` something from an `__aexit__` defined as an `async` function, that determines whether to suppress exceptions that got raised inside the block. A "truthy" value tells the `async with` to suppress exceptions, while a "falsy" value tells the `async with` to let exceptions propagate. The default `None` is falsy, so by default, exceptions are not suppressed.

Here's an example:

```
import asyncio

class Example:
    async def __aenter__(self):
        return 3
    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
        return True

async def example():
    async with Example() as three:
        print(three == 3)
        raise Exception
    print("Exception got suppressed")

asyncio.run(example())
```

[Output:](https://ideone.com/JjJzgg)

```
True
Exception got suppressed
```

Comment: I feel like the first sentence here is very misleading - focusing on a low-level implementation detail over the actual big-picture abstraction. Yes, it's true that generator functions return generator iterators and `async` functions return native coroutine objects. But given `async def f(): return 123` pretty much everyone would say "`f` returns 123", and given `async def f(): return None` pretty much everyone would say "`f` returns None" - because that is typically the most useful meaning of "return" and level of abstraction. And no `return` at all is same as `return None` in Python.

Comment: @mtraceur: I disagree; the low-level implementation detail is critical to resolving the misunderstanding. The language reference says that `__aenter__` and `__aexit__` must return awaitables, and the key to resolving the misunderstanding in the question is recognizing that these `__aenter__` and `__aexit__` methods do in fact return awaitables, despite the lack of a `return` statement. That said, I'll expand the answer to clarify.

Comment: (Also, I wouldn't consider "async functions return coroutine objects" to be an implementation detail. It's a central part of the async public API and a critical concept to understand when working with asyncio.)

Comment: Sorry, on further thought I agree with your main point - it is indeed directly relevant to resolving the asker's misunderstanding. I slipped up and let myself make a snap judgment about this answer without really fully digesting the question and what it needed.

Answer (score 3):

Your `__aenter__` method must return a context.

```
class MyAsyncContextManager:
    async def __aenter__(self):
        await log('entering context')
        # maybe some setup (e.g. await self.setup())
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
        # maybe closing context (e.g. await self.close())
        await log('exiting context')

    async def do_something(self):
        await log('doing something')
```

usage:

```
async with MyAsyncContextManager() as context:
    await context.do_something()
```

Comment: Not actually true. `__aenter__` is *allowed* to `return` something, but it doesn't have to. Not all context managers (async or not) need that functionality. (Also, if it does `return` something, that thing doesn't have to be "a context".)