# Must __aenter__ return an awaitable?

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.7

I'm confused by the definition of asynchronous context managers given in [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-context-managers-and-async-with):

> Two new magic methods are added: __aenter__ and __aexit__. Both must return an *awaitable*.

The example code is:

```
class AsyncContextManager:
    async def __aenter__(self):
        await log('entering context')

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
        await log('exiting context')
```

But these two coroutines don't return anything... *do they?*

---

Some possible solutions to this conundrum:

1. I don't understand what `await` does.
2. I don't know something about how functions choose their return value.
3. Both of the above.

Comment: Putting `async` before the `def` returns an awaitable. `__aenter__` itself can return anything it wants.

Comment: @dirn Thanks for the clarification. The terminology confused me!

Comment: This question is identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48390977/python-asynchronous-context-manager) but you'd never know it from the title of the other!